# Alterar booleano Django

Tags: python, django

gostaria de fazer um campo update que alterasse o valor do booleano para true ou false dentro de um modal para não ter que criar uma página só para editar o booleano.

eu tenho o seguinte código:
no model

```
class Tarefa(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(verbose_name="Titulo",max_length=30)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    data_vencimento = models.DateField(verbose_name="Vencimento")
    descricao = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descrição")
    concluido = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vencido = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

na view

```
def listTarefa(request):

    tarefas = Tarefa.objects.filter(usuario = request.user).order_by('data_vencimento')
    tarefas_vencidas = []
    tarefas_concluidas=[]
    tarefas_abertas = []


    for tarefa in tarefas:
        if tarefa.concluido:
            tarefas_concluidas.append(tarefa)
        else:

            if date.today() > tarefa.data_vencimento:
                tarefas_vencidas.append(tarefa)
            else:
                tarefas_abertas.append(tarefa)


    return render(request, 'listaTarefas.html', {'tarefas_abertas':tarefas_abertas,'tarefas_vencidas':tarefas_vencidas,
                                                 'tarefas_concluidas':tarefas_concluidas})
```

no forms

```
class ConcluirTarefaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tarefa
        fields = ['concluido',]
```

estou listando as tarefas tudo certo porem eu quero fazer um update para alterar o booleano.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como da pra ver na imagem ao clicar no buttom check abre um modal e nesse modal tem que ter o formulário para alterar o booleano da tarefa para true ou false.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a forma mais facil de fazer essa alteração seria via javascript, mas precisa ver como é feito o envio do seu form.

Comment: consegui em views.py mesmo obrigado!.